# Eloquent laravel WhereIn All

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to return all items with have all categories.

```
$items = DB::table('items')
              ->join('catitem_item', 'catitem_item.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
              ->whereIn('catitem_item.catitem_id', $cats)->paginate(10);
```

This query what I have now return items that have category 1 or 2 or 3.
What I need is return items that have category 1 and 2 and 3.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you expand your question more? it is hard to understand it. What is your output now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```php
$items = DB::table('items')
    ->join('catitem_item', 'catitem_item.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
    ->whereIn('catitem_item.catitem_id', $cats)
    ->groupBy('items.id')
    ->having(DB::raw('count(*)'), '=', count($cats))
    ->select('items.*')
    ->paginate(10);
```

With `HAVING count(*) = 3` the query will only return items that have all listed categories.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '3 ?' at line 1

Comment: @TomKur I fixed some issues. Try it now.

Comment: thx it worked, but I still need to join with other table listings which have many to many relationship with items which i think HAVING count(*) = 3 become invalid, because there will be more than 3 items count, any idea what changes should i make to the query?

Comment: I'd probably write a raw query with a subquery in it. Writing subqueries with the QueryBuilder is going to be very messy. Consider to write a new detailed question, since this one is already answered. Then post a link here, if you like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597329/eloquent-wherein-with-join-multiple-tables

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:
Where $cats= [1,2,3];

```
$items = DB::table('items')
->join('catitem_item', 'catitem_item.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
->whereIn('catitem_item.catitem_id', $cats)
->paginate(10);
```

its return items for category 1 and 2 and 3.that means its use for AND opration.

Comment: A column value can't be equal to three different values at the same time. `x = 1 AND x = 2 AND x = 3` is always FALSE. So your query will never return any rows.

Comment: yeah you are right,when we want all category then we'll do like above.