# select coordinates at other tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I want to get all nearest items, the coordinates are saved at listings table.
items and listings are many to many relationship.
Then it will be sorted either by distance or low to high price.

```
 $items = Item::with('listings')
               ->select('*');
if($request->sortby == 'distance'){
        $items->distance($lat,$lng);
      }
if($request->sortby == 'low'){
        $items->groupBy('listings.id')
              ->orderBy('items.price');
      }
$items = $items->paginate(10);
```

This is my Item model for distance

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $lat, $lng) {
        return $query->addSelect(DB::Raw('(3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( listings.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( listings.longitude ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(listings.latitude) ) ) ) AS distance'))
                  ->orderBy('distance');
    }
```

this requires listings.latitude and listings.longitude which are saved in listings table.
The error is

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'listings.latitude' in 'field list'

and if sorted low to high price

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'listings.id' in 'group
>   statement'

how to access/select coordinates and listings for these two sorts?

Comment: The group by seems incorrect to me anyway because not all fields in the select are functionally dependent on its value.

Comment: But I think the real issue is that `with` uses 2 separate queries behind the scenes, not a single query with joins.

Answer (score 0):

Your Items is collection of Item not a model, thus you cannot execute distance method on this object. You have to use foreach and find distance between user position and each of the Items.

```
foreach($items as $item) {   
    $distance=$item->distance($userPosition);   
}
```

Now in the `distance` method you will calculate distance between user position and Item.

Secondly change `$items->groupBy('listings.id')` to be `$items->groupBy('listing_id')` where `listing_id` is field on `items` table

Answer (score 0):

You may use join instead of eager loading here.

```
$items = Item::join('listings','listings.item_id','=','items.id')
               ->select('*');
```

Then use your logic here.

```
if($request->sortby == 'distance'){
        $items->distance($lat,$lng);
      }
if($request->sortby == 'low'){
        $items->groupBy('listings.id')
              ->orderBy('items.price');
      }
$items = $items->paginate(10);
```