# Laravel complex Eloquent Relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am developing chatting using Laravel

model ChattingRoom has these attribute :

```
$table->uuid('room_uuid');
$table->integer('user_id');
```

There are items like

```
room_uuid, user_id
r1, 1
r1, 2
r2, 1
r2, 2
r2, 3
r3, 2
r3, 3
```

room r1 has user 1,2.

room r2 has user 1,2,3.

room r3 has user 2,3.

i want to get room_uuid that has user 1 and 2.
Also I want to get room_uuid that has user 1,2,3.

I made query as following

```
with step0 as (
select room_uuid,0 as cnt
from chatting_rooms
where user_id = 1),
 step1 as (
     select room_uuid, 0 as cnt
     from chatting_rooms
     where user_id = 2
 ),
step2 as (
    select room_uuid, count(room_uuid) as cnt from chatting_rooms group by room_uuid having cnt =2
)
select step0.room_uuid
from step0,
    step1,
    step2
where step0.room_uuid = step1.room_uuid and step2.room_uuid = step0.room_uuid;
```

I want to use ChattingRoom model as following

ChattingRoom::getRoomUuid([1,2])

then it returns r1

ChattingRoom::getRoomUuid([1,2,3])

then it returns r2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use whereIn ...
$values=[1,2]'

```
    $room_uuid1=ChattingRoom::whereIn('user_id',$values)
->groupBy('chatting_rooms.user_id')
    ->having(DB::raw('count(*)'), '=', count($values))
->select('room_uuid')->get();
```

more details about whereIn in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45592687/10573560

Comment: $room_uuid1=ChattingRoom::whereIn('user_id',[1,2])->select('room_uuid')->get(); 
this will return r1 and r2.

Comment: you are right, how i missed that!.. any way .. i have updated my answer. please let me know if it helps